# python regex to match any strings $(*)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with some python regex as part of a script that I'm writing to generate simple shell scripts. I must be missing something really simple.

Example strings:

```
"$(VAR1)/mypath/to/nowhere"
"$(VAR2)"
"/cruel/$(VAR3)/world"
```

How can I match and return all `$(*)` values from the strings? I've tried a bunch of different regexes similar to `'$\((*)\)'`, but I'm not getting any matches in a python regex tester. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: To get what is inside, use `re.findall(r'\$\(([^()]+)\)', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
s = "$(VAR1)/cruel/$(VAR3)/world"
result = re.findall(r'\$\([^()]+\)', s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['$(VAR1)', '$(VAR3)']
```

Comment: i was way off on my regex... need to do some reading on this.